# (Django) How to pre-populate multiple images edit form if every image is an object of many-to-one relation?

Tags: django-forms

I have a One-to-Many relation between FirstModel and SecondModel (which consist of firstmodel_id and image).
I am trying to make an edit view for a model, so existing data must be populated to a form.

Here is my view.py code.

```
def update_view(request, pk):

    preloaded_data = FirstModel.objects.get(id=pk)
    preloaded_imgs = SecondModel.objects.filter(firstmodel_id=pk)
    form = FirstForm(instance=preloaded_data)
    imgs = SecondForm(instance=preloaded_imgs)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'imgs': imgs,
    }
    return render(request, 'new_instance.html', context)
```

Rest of the code is seams to be fine, since if i exclude preloaded_imgs and imgs it works just fine.

I have been using

```
form = Form(instance=preloaded_data)
```

for text and int data, however its doesn't work for multiple images.
(i have also tried to prepopulate a single photo with:

```
preloaded_imgs = Photo.objects.filter(form_id=pk).first()
img = PhotoForm(instance=preloaded_imgs)
```

it renders the form but its empty..)

Please at lease gimme a vector for further investigation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is not possible to populate file form for browsers safety reasons. The only solution I found out so far is to render images associated with current object and add logic to delete them (one by one or all at once) by id/ids. The form will only used to add new images.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).